# POST works with alert message but doesn't without it

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script, web-applications

I am making a post request to google app script with the code below

```
    var url ="MY WEBAPP EXEC"

     function submitForm() {
        var postRequest = {}
        postRequest.name = $("#inputName").val();
        postRequest.email = $("#inputEmail1").val();
        postRequest.message = $("#inputMessage").val();

        alert(JSON.stringify(postRequest));  // this alert

        $.post(url, postRequest, function(data,status){
           alert('success')
        });
    }
```

I am very confused why the post is working with the alert but doesn't work without it.  Thank you.

===
OK I guess my question was not clear enough sorry.

I have a form accessing GAS remotely.  I assumed the url implied that I was accessing GAS remotely.  At the moment I am working on my localhost and on my JS above it works if the alert statement is present and does not do anything if alert is not there.

I was watching the execution list on GSuite Developer Hub to see if the request failed or completed.  I observed if the alert statement is in the script the execution status is completed but if the alert statement is not there nothing happens.  I assume that my post script is not working if alert is not there.  Any idea why?

Comment: when it "doesn't work", what happens instead?

Comment: @JaromandaX "doesn't work" obviously means, that the alert is not being displayed... because it has no single other function than being displayed.

Comment: Nothing.  I check on the execution list of GSuite Developer Hub and nothing happens there.

Comment: If I delete the alert statement nothing happens, it only works if the alert is there.

Comment: @MartinZeitler - clearly if the alert isn't there it isn't displayed

Comment: the issue is probably how you're calling submitForm function - does `function submitForm(e) { e.prevendDefault(); ... rest of your code }` help?

Comment: @JaromandaX the UI has it's own client-side scripts queued - and as my answer suggests, that alert should be pushed into that server-side queue with `google.script.run`, which runs these client-side scripts; else changes are good it may interfere.

Comment: oh ... didnt' see that this was some google stuff - my bad

Comment: I did your e.preventDefault() @JaromandaX ... it's working!  You can put that on the answer so that I can vote on it.  Thank you!

Comment: @Martin It's not client side web-app. This is a remote web-app script(running @ http://localhost ?) posting to a published gas-webapp. Jaromanda is right.

Comment: @TheMaster the `$` clearly hints for jQuery... which is client-side _script_.

Comment: @Martin Yes. Jquery running in local host/OP's own website... client side is not at script.google.com and there's no `google.script.run`

Comment: @TheMaster think you didn't read the question too well; it is tagged `google-app-script`. that jQuery script runs in an `iframe` sidebar or modal dialog - nevertheless it is being displayed with GAS and that name-space is available; the situation commonly are two client-side scripts running side-by-side - which can interact through the backend with `google.script.run`.

Comment: @Martin The GAS is a published web-app (with no client side in this case). You can POST to a GAS url from anywhere in the world. That's my point. See [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content) : `doGet()and doPost() are invoked whenever a request is made to the script's URL` Here, A POST request is made to the script's published url remotely from localhost/ another website. The script posted above doesn't run in a ``iframe``(Although that's more common)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown exactly how that function is called, but it's likely to be because, if this is truly a "form submit" action, the result of submitting a form is to "load a new page" (which can be the same page you're on, and is so by default with no `action` attribute in the form tag

Since you want to perform AJAX on form submit, you need to "prevent" the "default" form submit action - this can be achieved as shown in the second and third lines below

```
 var url ="MY WEBAPP EXEC"
 function submitForm(e) { // if this function is called using an event handler, it gets an event as the first and only argument
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the "default" form submit action
    var postRequest = {}
    postRequest.name = $("#inputName").val();
    postRequest.email = $("#inputEmail1").val();
    postRequest.message = $("#inputMessage").val();

    alert(JSON.stringify(postRequest));  // this alert

    $.post(url, postRequest, function(data,status){
       alert('success')
    });
}
```

Comment: I customized my function call to have the event parameter.  Thanks!